# Bringing pre-made bird's nest soup into the UK

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink, import-taxes

I have an Asian tourist who wants to bring into the UK bags of pre-made [bird's nest soup](http://naturalnews.com/034342_birds_nest_soup_cave_swiftlets_food.html) which is apparently very expensive in Asia and needs some advice on this.

Is this item allowed? If so, what import duty applies and what do they need to know about customs and agricultural restrictions to do this?

Comment: I am not sure how this is travel related?  Seems more like business or economics.

Comment: It seems like more of a trivia question than an actual travel problem someone has because travelers rarely shop with the intent of maximizing the import duty they pay. Questions about specific items would be on-topic though.

Comment: @ZachLipton : Question is in fact highly relevant and I need definitive answers. What would you do if you have a newly established travel agency and your asian tourists ask you this question and need some advice? Shall I tell the traveler your question is irrelevant. How should I advise an old foreigner what she can bring into the country without being grilled in the customs?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's [not a question about an actual problem](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) that a traveler would face.

Comment: What's the actual question a traveler has then? It's not this one, because the answer could be something like "car parts from Swaziland" or "beef tongues from these six countries" because of the incredible complexity of the tariff system. Whatever the "Asian tourists" or "old foreigner" want to know, it's not this trivia question.

Comment: I have this Asian tourist who wants to bring in bags of pre-made birds nest soup which is apparently very expensive in Asia and needs some advice on this. To get the picture of the kind of item I am talking about have a look at : http://www.naturalnews.com/034342_birds_nest_soup_cave_swiftlets_food.html

Comment: Ok. Great. That's a specific and answerable question. Can I edit this to be about birds nest soup instead of "items" in general?

Comment: Of course you can.

Comment: Thanks. I gave it a shot. Welcome to travel.stackexchange!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not allowed:

> If you are travelling from a country outside the EU, you cannot bring
>   any meat or dairy products into the UK unless you are travelling from
>   the Faroe Islands, Greenland or Iceland, when you are allowed a
>   combined weight of up to 10kg per person. You may bring in a limited
>   quantity of other animal products, such as fish, bivalves, honey and
>   eggs.

See [this handy PDF](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/531649/Bringing_food_into_the_UK_leaflet.pdf) (quoted above) for more information.

Comment: Why is it not allowed? Bird's nest is an animal product but is clearly neither meat nor dairy nor egg nor fish; it is dried bird spit. I believe it is an exempted food product described by the last bullet [here](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/personal-food-plant-and-animal-product-imports#exempted-food-products). Why should I think otherwise?